# How to establish cross account role account between multiple AWS accounts with write permission ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have 3 AWS accounts lets say A,B and C. We established cross account policies for S3 buckets between A and B , A and C. We created an instance in B with S3 roles. We uploaded files from the instance to the bucket residing in account A. By default it is setting the owner of the files as B even though it is residing in A.After this when we are trying to access the files from the account C we are getting the permission issues.

PFB the error.

> A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the GetObjectAcl
>   operation: Access Denied

How to resolve this issue ? 
Is it possible to modify the owner of the files in S3 bucket ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use STS to access from cross AWS account like

```
var params = {
    RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::crossaccountNumber:role/crossAccountName', /* required, cross account role */
    RoleSessionName: 'Demo-RoleSession', /* required */
    DurationSeconds: 3600
};
var sts = new AWS.STS({
    apiVersion: '2011-06-15',
    accessKeyId: 'accessKeyIdValue', // Original Account accessKeyId
    secretAccessKey: 'secretAccessKeyValue' // Original Account secretAccessKey
});

sts.assumeRole(params, function (err, data) {
     // Access S3 bucket 
}); //data var content temp Credentials
```